# jQuery - Clearing textarea on change of select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm building a little text editor that allows editing of files and also allows a new file to be created. This is how my select menu is configured.

```
<select name="reportname" id="reportname" class="form-control">
    <option value="zrxqy">--Choose a Report--</option>
    <option value="newReport">--Create a New Report--</option>
    <optgroup label="General Reports">
        <option name="Volumes" id="Volumes" value="volumes.php">Volumes</option>
        <option name="Options" id="Options" value="Options.php">Options</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

There's a `<textarea>` below this that display the contents of the selected report file. `id="reporttxt"`. When the `select` is changed, I want the contents of the textarea cleared and then the new file contents put in. This works when switching between files, but if a user inputs text, it breaks the clearing.

I've tried just this:

```
$("#reportname").change(function(){
    $("reporttxt").html('') //this works when switching between functions
    //function to import new text <-- this works fine
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
$("#reportname").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "newReport"){
        $("#reporttxt").val(''); //this clears user input but now nothing will display
    } else {
        $("#reporttxt").html('');
    }
    //function to import text <-- does not display text after .val('') is fired
});
```

The function import text inserts it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "report-data.php",
    data: "file="+$(this).val(),
    datatype: "json",
    success: function( result ) {
        $("#reporttxt").append(result.body);
    }
});
```

Any ideas why these weird things happen?

**EDIT**

the problem was actually the `.append()`.

I'm not sure why but changing

```
$("#reporttxt").append(result.body);
```

to

```
$("#reporttxt").val(result.body);
```

fixed the problem. I am just using `$("#reporttxt").val('');` to clear now.

Comment: You're using the class selector, not the ID selector  $('#reportname')......

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've corrected it.

Comment: Why are you using append to set text on text area? Call val() to set text on text area as you did in change function.

Comment: Cool. You may like to mark my reply as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting answer...
Call val() to set text on text area as you did in change function..
This is to answer why append() doesn't work. The append() just add another node to caller node in HTML DOM.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `ajax` function has no `date` setting like you used it here: `date: "file="+$(this).val(),`. I think you meant `data` or am I wrong?